# "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised values" while freeing a char **

Tags: c, pointers, unix, valgrind

I'm writing a minimalist shell in C for school. It works fine, but using Valgrind I'm getting this error and i can't figure out what I did wrong. I get it at the start of the program:

> ```
> ==9396== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==9396==    at 0x1093AC: get_env (msh.c:59)
> ==9396==    by 0x1094FA: main (msh.c:106)
> ==9396==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
> ==9396==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
> ==9396==    by 0x109341: get_env (msh.c:55)
> ==9396==    by 0x1094FA: main (msh.c:106)
> ==9396==
> ```

At the beginning, I do a copy of the environement variables (`extern char **environ`) in the `main()`:

```
 if (!(env = get_env(environ)))
         return (1);
```

Here's the function:

```
 char    **get_env(char **environ)
 {
          char    **copy;
          char    **env_ptr;
          char    **cpy_ptr;

          if (!(copy = malloc(sizeof(copy) * get_tab_size(environ) + 1)))
                  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          env_ptr = environ;
          cpy_ptr = copy;
          while (*cpy_ptr)
          {
                  if (!(*cpy_ptr = ft_strdup(*env_ptr)))
                          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                  cpy_ptr++;
                  env_ptr++;
          }
          cpy_ptr = NULL;
          return (copy);
  }
```

At the end of the program, I free the copy with this function and get the same error:

> ```
> ==9396== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==9396==    at 0x10BFC0: ft_free_tab2 (in /home/pom/dev/19/msh/msh)
> ==9396==    by 0x109593: main (msh.c:126)
> ==9396==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
> ==9396==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
> ==9396==    by 0x109341: get_env (msh.c:55)
> ==9396==    by 0x1094FA: main (msh.c:106)
> ```

Here's the freeing function:

```
  void    ft_free_tab2(char **env)
  {
          char    **ptr;

          if (!env)
                  return ;
          ptr = env;
          while (*ptr)
          {
                  free(*ptr);
                  ptr++;
          }
          free(env);
  }
```

I also get the problem when other parts of the program use the copy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect the value of `*cpy_ptr` to be on the first iteration of the loop in `get_env`?

Comment: @dbush oops.. should have been *env_ptr.. thanks for pointing that out. The first error disappeared, thanks. However I still have it while freeing, and on some other parts of the program using it.

Comment: You didn't allocate enough memory. You've got `size * size + 1` when you should have `size * (size + 1)`. In other words, you need to allocate space for one more pointer, but the code you've got allocates space for one more byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you allocate some uninitialized memory for copy.

```
copy = malloc(sizeof(copy) * get_tab_size(environ) + 1)
```

Then you make a pointer pointing to it.

```
cpy_ptr = copy;
```

So far so good, but then you do this:

```
while (*cpy_ptr)
```

`copy`, and thus also `cpy_ptr` is pointing at uninitialized memory. You need to initialize it before dereferencing the pointer.

I would also remark that you use `sizeof(copy)` instead of `sizeof(*copy)`. Sure, it gives the same result in this case, but that's only because it's a double pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your expression:

```
while (*cpy_ptr)
```

is testing the malloced, uninitialized space. You probably want to be testing the original:

```
while (*env_ptr)
```

I.e. while we have not reached the end of the original null-terminated vector of strings ...

Also, your last line is dubious:

```
cpy_ptr = NULL;
```

That has no effect, because you're assigning to a local variable that has no next-use before going out of scope. You almost certainly wanted this:

```
*cpy_ptr = NULL;  // Null-terminate the copied vector
```

Comment: Thanks. As I was saying to dbush, I fixed this but still get the same error while freeing and other parts of the program.

Comment: Your freeing function assumes that the vector of pointers has been properly terminated by a null pointer.  Without the `*cpy_ptr = NULL` fix, we are leaving garbage in `*cpy_ptr`, and Valgrind detects that for us.

Comment: @Zest For each pointer you use in a conditional expression, ask and answer for yourself two questions: (1) "What is the pointer pointing to?" (e.g. what address does the pointer hold) and (2) "Is there something valid stored there?" Until you can confirm both, you may well have an uninitialized value you are attempting base a jump or conditional move on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did set cpy_ptr instead of *cpy_ptr to NULL. Solved it!